# Disable smooth scroll in Bootstrap 5 with html/css code

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have some anchor links on my website, and when clicking on them - smooth scroll (Bootstrap feature) turns on and it scrolls smoothly.

Due to the specificity of my website I need to disable smooth scrolling in my html or css code.

Thanks in advance!

Found some solutions with some js code, but it's not what I need.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/options/ - `$enable-smooth-scroll`

Answer (score 4):

You can disable smooth scrolling by using the scroll-behavior property in CSS (there is **scroll-behavior: smooth** in Bootstrap 5).

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: thank you, that worked!
that's what I've been looking for :)